# Add datetime in filename produce error - python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to write file with datetime but it produce error. I did refer to all source but still i get error, and trying to understand what i'm missing here. Any help is highly appreciated.

example code:

```
current_dt = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%d.%m.%Y-%H:%M:%S")
filepath =r'testtable_%s.xlsx'%current_dt
with pd.Excelwriter(filepath)as f:
    df2.to_excel(f, sheet_name='SH-1',index=False)
    df.to_excel(f, sheet_name='SH-2',index=False)
```

error: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'testtable_11.08.2023-08:45:05.xlsx'

Comment: Windows doesn't allow colons `:` in filenames. That's all

Answer (score 0):

Replace the dots and colon in the filepath:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timezone

current_dt = datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime("%d.%m.%Y-%H:%M:%S")
print(current_dt)
char_remov = [":", "."]
for char in char_remov:
    # replace() "returns" an altered string
    current_dt = current_dt.replace(char, "_")

print(current_dt)

filepath =f'testtable_{current_dt}.xlsx'
print(filepath)
```